# Change UITextField borderColor in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, xamarin

I need to change a UITextField's borderColor to White in Xamarin.

I tried setting it's `layer.borderColor` and also runtime attributes in XCode IB but it was of no use.

Could someone please help me in achieving this?

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8204/ios-7-uibutton-with-single-line-border

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should get you there:

```
var textField = new UITextField();

textField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;
textField.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;
```

If that does not work, please show more code. Because then I presume your overwriting the style somewhere.

Comment: LOL seriously I dont understand what I was trying. I was not setting the BorderWidth which obviously does not show up the border.

Answer (score -1):

Control.Layer.BorderColor = Color.FromHex ("1B9AF7").ToCGColor();

Comment: The asker has already stated that they attempted to set its `layer.borderColor` so this answer is unhelpful.